# Connecting jittered data points with lines - seaborn python

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn, visualization, jitter

Is there a way to extract the x-axis values of the jittered points in the middle plot as generated by the code below?

See the issue [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6RsZ.jpg)

```py
# import libraries
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
sns.stripplot(x="variable", y="value", data=pupil_long_df, dodge=True, jitter=True, alpha=.40, zorder=1, size=8, linewidth = 1)
sns.pointplot(x='variable', y='value', ci=95,data=pupil_long_df, join=False, scale=1, zorder=100, color='black', capsize = 0.05, palette = 'Paired') 

# Add lines between the points
lines3 = plt.plot([df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1]], color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5, linestyle = '--')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be terribly impractical to extract the x-values of the stripplot... My standard advice is that if you want to do something more than the standard plots offered by seaborn, then it's usually easier to just recreate them by hand. See the code below:

```
N=20
# dummy dataset
data = np.random.normal(size=(N,))
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition 1': data,
                   'condition 2': data+1,
                   'condition 3': data,
                   'condition 4': data-1})

jitter = 0.05
df_x_jitter = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=jitter, size=df.values.shape), columns=df.columns)
df_x_jitter += np.arange(len(df.columns))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in df:
    ax.plot(df_x_jitter[col], df[col], 'o', alpha=.40, zorder=1, ms=8, mew=1)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
ax.set_xlim(-0.5,len(df.columns)-0.5)

for idx in df.index:
    ax.plot(df_x_jitter.loc[idx,['condition 1','condition 2']], df.loc[idx,['condition 1','condition 2']], color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5, linestyle = '--', zorder=-1)
    ax.plot(df_x_jitter.loc[idx,['condition 3','condition 4']], df.loc[idx,['condition 3','condition 4']], color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5, linestyle = '--', zorder=-1)
```

[image]